# WSO2 EI - Proxy Services with Load Balancer

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

When i need to put Load Balancer to Proxy Service deployed on WSO2 EI 6.5.0,

Would i need to implement Clustering with it?

**1. I found below sample on Docs :**

```
       <loadbalance algorithm="org.apache.synapse.endpoints.algorithms.RoundRobin">
          <endpoint>
             <address uri="service_url (instance21">
                <enableAddressing/>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                   <initialDuration>20000</initialDuration>
                   <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
             </address>
          </endpoint>
          <endpoint>
             <address uri="service_url (instance2)">
                <enableAddressing/>
                <suspendOnFailure>
                   <initialDuration>20000</initialDuration>
                   <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
                </suspendOnFailure>
             </address>
          </endpoint>
       </loadbalance>
```

it is the right way to create LB ?

**2. I tried it below too  :**

**https://medium.com/@snsavithrik1/wso2-ei-worker-manager-clustering-on-a-single-machine-dae1161bcb78**

```
but i think that is not balancing service load through all proxy It only handles request 
it's Manager node, Worker node does nothing
```

Note `: i expect that when i send request to proxy services, if this service is busy, it sends coming requests to other node to handling it`

**Something like this :**

```
[LOG] Response from service1
[LOG] Response from service2
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation on [1]. The provided blog does not contain the load balancer configuration. Further to add to this, in the EI servers we do not have the concept of the worker, manager. This was a concept introduced in the ESB servers where the worker nodes serve the requests and the manager node was used to manage the artifacts deployed.

[1]-https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Clustering+the+ESB+Profile

Comment: It is not necessary to cluster the nodes to have a load balancer configured. It is only necessary to cluster the if you have implemented configurations such as scheduled tasks, inbound endpoint, message processors, etc. In the clustered environment they will execute only in one node.